# KeyDown procedure is throwing 2 compile errors

Tags: dll, vb6

I get two types of Compile errors when trying to compile a form. It happens with any sub that includes the KeyDown procedures. The first error I get is

> "User-defined type not defined"

The other error I get is:

> "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or
>   procedure having the same name"

I have linked the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library. When I do this the "User-defined type not defined" error changes to the procedure error. I cannot find anywhere where this has been an issue for someone else.

```
Private Sub cmbDriverNumber_KeyDown(Index As Integer, KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, Shift As Integer)
    Call cView.sendBack(KeyCode, Shift, Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: *Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library* is the library used by Microsoft Office's VBA environment for GUIs - unless you have a compelling/specific reason to so you should not be using it in VB6 - or are you actually using VBA?

Comment: No, its definitely VB6. I am new to visual basic. I inherited an application that is ancient and no one who remains at the company knows the code. I wasn't originally brought on to work on this specific product. From what I understand, the author designed this with MS Forms 2.0

Comment: On the form click on the `cmbDriverNumber` control, in the Properties window for it is there a value for *Index* ? If not just delete `Index As Integer, ` from the event sub.

Answer (score 1):

First, I was under the impression that it was not recommend to use the MS Forms library since it was more an internal library used in MS Office applications.  (I have used this library though).  YMMV.

Second, `User-defined type not defined` would be expected if you are copy-pasting some code into you application that relies on MS Forms but you have not yet added a reference to that library to you project.

Third, the code snippet you have includes an `Index`, which means it is getting called by a control array.  If this code was just something you pasted into the application, and you are not using an array of `cmbDriverNumber` controls, then the signature is wrong.  Instead, try to remove `Index As Integer,` from the event signature.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for responding, I inherited this project/product and it is well outside my expertise. I don't know why the original author wrote it the way they did; however, I do know that the project was able to compile the way it was written but will not now. I should have mentioned this all in the post

Comment: I'd still take a look at the last suggestion I included, it would cause the error message you are seeing.

Comment: I removed the Index portion of the signature, it still threw the same error. I used the below answer to some results However, I ran into some other situations where I got the same error but the signature is sufficiently different that I couldn't use that solution. I came across the idea that VB IDE is referencing a control variable as an array variable. I haven't had much success in using this toward a resolution. [link](https://www.c-amie.co.uk/technical/visual-basic-6-0-error-compile-error-procedure-declaration-does-not-match-description-of-event-or-procedure-having-the-same-name/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simple answer is just to define your return variable as an Integer, since that is how the KeyDown event is defined.  I'm not familiar with the MSForms library, but is it possible that the type of the element of the MSForms type is something other than an integer (like a Long, perhaps)?

Comment: Did you mean KeyCode when you wrote "return variable" ?

Comment: Thanks this worked, to a degree. I ran into other code that threw the same error that had no references to MSForms. This is a project that has certainly compiled before and I'm thinking there is a deeper issue that I'm not seeing.